# JVM Crash with SIGSEGV - problematic frame - libzip.so

Tags: java, tomcat7, java-7

JVM crashes strangely from time to time. The problematic frame in JVM crash log is libzip.so and error is SIGSEGV. This occurs in Tomcat 7 and JDK 7

Here is the Stack Trace for reference:

> Stack: [0x00007f68b999c000,0x00007f68b9a9d000],  sp=0x00007f68b9a99770,
>
> free space=1013k Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted,
> Vv=VM code, C=native code) C  [libzip.so+0x8099]  deflate_slow+0x49 C
>
> [libzip.so+0x7433]  deflate+0x163 C  [libzip.so+0x3049]
>
> Java_java_util_zip_Deflater_deflateBytes+0x269 j
> java.util.zip.Deflater.deflateBytes(J[BIII)I+0 J 3307 C2
> java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.finish()V (135 bytes) @
>
> org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.FlushableGZIPOutputStream.finish()V+9
> j  org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.GzipOutputFilter.end()J+26 j
> org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.endRequest()V+43 J 2372
> C2
>
> org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(Lorg/apache/coyote/ActionCode;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
> (602 bytes) @ 0x00007f6a4d759c84 [0x00007f6a4d759a80+0x204] J 2733 C2
> org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Lorg/apache/coyote/ActionCode;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>
> (37 bytes) @ 0x00007f6a4d8b9ad0 [0x00007f6a4d8b9a80+0x50] j
> org.apache.coyote.Response.finish()V+5 j
> org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close()V+138 j
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.close()V+4 j
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+467
> j
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+55
> j
> org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+56
> j
> org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+23
> j
> org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)Z+385
> j
> org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Lorg/apache/struts/config/ForwardConfig;)V+74
> j
> org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+267
> j
> org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+40
> j
> org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+3
> j
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+35
> j
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+30
> J 2406 C2
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
> (624 bytes) @ 0x00007f6a4d7760e4 [0x00007f6a4d775da0+0x344] J 2407 C2
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
> (105 bytes) @ 0x00007f6a4d5b2154 [0x00007f6a4d5b2120+0x34] j
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+21
> J 2406 C2
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
> (624 bytes) @ 0x00007f6a4d775f28 [0x00007f6a4d775da0+0x188] J 2407 C2
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
> (105 bytes) @ 0x00007f6a4d5b2154 [0x00007f6a4d5b2120+0x34] j
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Lorg/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationDispatcher$State;)V+393
> j
>
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Lorg/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationDispatcher$State;)V+98

This issue occurs only after migrating to JDK 7 + Tomcat7. It was working fine in the lower versions. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a jni call in stack trace, try to run jvm with `-Xcheck:jni` option ( I am not sure if it will detect some errors in your case).

This crash occurs while compressing output stream in tomcat filter. You can disable compression in connector ( [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html) )

Also as I see, error occurs in `deflate_slow` method, you can turn off tomcat GzipOutputFilter and create your custom filter with DeflaterOutputStream and set compression level between 1-3 ( In this case `deflate_fast` method will be choosen in hotspot)

Answer (score 0):

Please use -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true to avoid such crash, JDK9 has better mechanism to handle such crashes. If it is feasible please upgrade to use JDK9